# WaitForExit() throws exception c#

Tags: c#, .net

Below is my code to start the process, have put link for demo only.I want this process to run in background without opening browser. Also 2nd line throws exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
var process=Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Ugh! Obviously, already your `Process.Start(..)` failed!

Comment: no that did opened my browse with link

Comment: But the exception says that your `process` var is `null`! I'm not talking about open windows here, but about variable values in code...

Comment: thanx ya thats null, is there any workarond to this and also to open it in background and not opening any tab of browser

Comment: "not opening any tab of browser" - then what do you *expect* to happen. If you were to type that exact text into the Run dialog, it would cause a browser window/tab to open - that's it's entire effect. What are you expecting instead?

Comment: i mean opening in backgorund, coz i am just going to download one xml file from link to my local folder

Comment: If you just want to download a file to a local file, you should be using `WebClient.DownloadFile` or any of its moral equivalents. Why are you launching a separate process?

Comment: yes thats what i have exactly done on later stage, but i forgot to tell u that corresponding file is generated when i call this link

Comment: So you don't need `Process` at all. What you're asking for is nothing but  a simple `WebRequest`. See [here](http://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/simple-web-request-with-web-response/215) on how to do it.

Comment: @Nitinvarpe DownloadFile() will _call_ that URL like your browser does.

Comment: @ThomasWeller thank you very much, your suggestion to work with WebRequest worked like charm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you start a process *indirectly* you won't get `Process` object (then in your case process is always `null` and second line throws an exception).

Let me explain what I mean with *indirectly*: if you don't specify an executable but you give a document (or a resource) then it'll be *executed* through a shell verb. In this case an existing process may be (re)used. In this cases `Process.Start()` will return `null`.

Try this:

- Create an empty Word document 'c:\test.docx'.
- Close all Word instances.
- Execute `Process.Start(@"c:\test.docx"); // Returns a Process instance`
- Execute `Process.Start(@"c:\test.docx"); // Returns null`

Can you **simply** solve this? AFAIK you can't because `Process` uses `ShellExecuteEx` with a [SHELLEXECUTEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure to start the process. Reading `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` documentation for `hProcess` field you'll see that:

> A handle to the newly started application. This member is set on return and is always NULL unless fMask is set to SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS. Even if fMask is set to SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS, **hProcess will be NULL if no process was launched. For example, if a document to be launched is a URL and an instance of Internet Explorer is already running, it will display the document. No new process is launched, and hProcess will be NULL.**
>   Note  ShellExecuteEx does not always return an hProcess, even if a process is launched as the result of the call. For example, an hProcess does not return when you use SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST to invoke IContextMenu.

**Note** if you're running a new process just to open an URL and get a server side generated file then you should follow [Damien's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) and use a `WebClient.DownloadFile()`.

Comment: What do you mean by indirectly?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Use of DDE or IDropTarget to re-use an existing process.

Comment: @Adriano does this means if i close browser and run app, it will not throw any error

Comment: @Nitinvarpe yes (if no browser instances are running _hidden_ in background)

Answer (score 1):

`Process.Start()` can return a null reference:

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Diagnostics.Process
>
> A new Process component that is associated with the process resource, *or null, if no process resource is started* (for example, if an existing process is reused).

(Emphasis mine)

When that happens, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to call `WaitForExit()`